# How to use 'be' verbs, word 'be'?

Tags: grammar, tenses

Randomly I texted my teacher regarding tuition fee which I transferred through the bank.

The text was: `Money transferred`, but I feel some wrong in this text and observed keenly and I found that the correct sentence is `Money was transferred`. I am embarking curiosity in my mind what is the difference between the two sentences, some knowledge to identify those errors any online tool to detect those errors, remake it to correct one.

PS: Edits are welcome. Sorry for the poor English.

Comment: Hello, kvk. This is a common practice in telegrams of old, headlines, texts and the like. Deletions have been made from 'The [relevant] money has been transferred'. It is not 'wrong', but wouldn't be used in formal writing.

Answer (score 0):

If we weren't simply speaking about text speech and the lax sentence structure inherent to it, the difference would be that "Money was transferred" refers to "the money" as the object of the sentence that the verb (transferred) was done to; "Money transferred" would mean that "money" was the subject who did the transferring. Similarly, "Jane led" (Jane is leading others) vs "Jane was led" (Jane was being led by someone).